# Jenkins master(s) as a slave of another master(s)

Tags: jenkins, distributed, master-slave, executors, jenkins-scriptler

This may be a crazy idea but I'm just throwing it.

Is it possible to have one Jenkins master's executors available as slave(s) (executors) from another Jenkins Master?

I.e. Let's say JenkinsMaster1 (has 10 executors). It has bunch of slaves (in various OS with various # of executors per slave) but all of them are used/running something.

There's another JenkinsMaster2 and this instance has the same setup (bunch of slaves with N no. of executors) but this one has some/a lot of free executors (on master or it's slaves).

The question is NOT, why I can't just create a new slave for JenkinsMaster1 if I need a job configured in JenkinsMaster1 instance to run (while every other executor in JenkinsMaster1/its slave are in use) **or** why not add more/increase executors of JenkinsMaster1 master/slaves **BUT** **how can**/**is it even possible** to use JenkinsMaster2's executors (or it's slaves i.e. owned by JenkinsMaster2) to run a job which is configured on JenkinsMaster1.

Comment: It sounds possible. All you would need to do is retrieve the job configuration from JenkinsMaster1 using the REST api and create that same job on JenkinsMaster2 using the REST api.

Comment: @hofan41 thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I know that's if you want to create the job on JenkinsMaster2. But, I don't want that actually (for ex: If job does deployments or some work then the user will be confused to run job from which instance). What I meant is, can I run the job (configured in JenkinsMaster1) on the executors of JenkinsMaster2 or any of the slave's executors of JenkinsMaster2?

Comment: It's more than likely impossible. How would the slave report status? How would the slave send logs? How would any master know about the slave? What you're asking for is convoluted and therefore, unlikely to be supported.

Comment: @hofan41 agree, that's why it was a crazy idea! I'll keep looking .... if that's possible, thanks.